# Mi código de ACF no funciona (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy creando un código en mi web de pruebas con WordPress ([Gestión de documentos](https://gestion-documental.000webhostapp.com/2017/03/14/estadistica-descriptiva/)) utilizando el plugin ACF (Advanced Custom Fields). Además he incorporado el código en el archivo "content.php" del tema. Sin embargo el código presenta un error que aún desconozco, ya que el último "loop" siempre muestra la información del post actual.

Este es el código (actualizado):

```
<!-- MOSTRAR CAMPOS PERSONALIZADOS -->
<!-- Documento principal -->

<?php
$attachment_id = get_field('archivo');
$url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
$title = get_the_title($attachment_id);
$path_info = pathinfo(get_attached_file($attachment_id));
$filesize = filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment_id ) );
$filesize = size_format($filesize, 2);

if(get_field('archivo')): ?>
  <div class="titulos_secundarios">Ver documento:</div><br/><br/>
  <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank" 
     title="Abrir documento en una nueva pestaña" 
     style="display: inline;"><?php echo $title?>.<?php 
  echo $path_info['extension'];?> (<?php echo $filesize; ?>)</a>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Documento secundarios -->

<br/>
<div class="titulos_secundarios">Antecedentes</div>
<br/>

<?php 
if(have_rows('otros_archivos')):
  while (have_rows('otros_archivos')) : the_row();
    $post_object = get_sub_field('antecedente');
    echo "<ol>";
    if($post_object): 
      $post = $post_object; setup_postdata($post); ?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata();
    else:
      echo "<li>No se ha incluido ningún antecedente aún.</li><br/>";
    endif;
    echo "</ol>";
  endwhile;
endif; ?>
<!-- FIN MOSTRAR CAMPOS PERSONALIZADOS -->
```

¡Gracias por su sugerencias!

Comment: Asegurate de que los valores estan correctamente guardados en la base de datos. Si no tienes acceso a la DB mediante phpmyAdmin, entonces inspecciona los valores de post_meta que hay asociados al post. Justo despues de '<?php' coloca: `$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() ); echo '<pre>' . pre_print($meta) . '</pre>';`A partir de ahi veremos que podemos hacer.

Comment: Pude resolver el error del código, pero el último loop muestra siempre el link y el título de la entrada actual.

Answer (score 0):

Y si intentas enviandole el id del post.

```
get_field('archivo', $post->ID)
```

Comment: Lo probé y no funciona.